# Merging intersecting polygons to single polygon

Tags: javascript, geometry, polygon, raphael, intersection

**Question :**

I want to remove overlaps from existing polygons with javascript.

I guess merging overlapping polygons to single polygon is the easiest way to do this but i don't know  how to do this.

[image: I want to combine theese polygons] 
[image: This is the resault i want to achive]

Comment: Just wondering if there is some simpler workaround. Is the main aim trying to get the polygons together as one, or is that a workaround for something else you are trying to achieve, if so, whats that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement [Vatti's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm) or use some polygon library which realizes it (or other reliable algo).

[Clipper library](http://www.angusj.com/clipper2/Docs/Overview.htm) uses this algorithm, but seems it has not JavaScript binding yet.

Javascript port exists for [GPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Polygon_Clipper) (sometimes less robust)

Comment: Your post is solved my problem.Thanks for helping.
Also i added a working example link to my main post.I found it in GPC Examples.

Comment: The post is out of date, as the two links below don't work.

Comment: Links were updated

Answer (score 3):

Since @MBo's answer is out of date, here is a new answer. The math has already been written down in JavaScript:

- [polygon-clipping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/polygon-clipping)
- [martinez-polygon-clipping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/martinez-polygon-clipping)

`polygonClipping.union(triangle, hexagon, house, diamond)` (from the first package) returns the polygons like in your question.